# Sum to $n$ terms.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Evaluate the following expression:

$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i \cdot 2^{i}}{(i+2)!}$

I can't find a way to use telescoping sums here. What else could be done?

Comment: There is a way to get rid of the denominator within the sum, by factoring out $\frac1{(n+2)!}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{i\cdot 2^i}{(i+2)!}=\frac{(i+2-2)\cdot 2^i}{(i+2)!}=\frac{2^i}{(i+1)!}-\frac{2^{i+1}}{(i+2)!}$$

Observe that if we set $\displaystyle \frac{2^i}{(i+1)!}=f(i),$ 
$\displaystyle\frac{2^{i+1}}{(i+2)!}=f(i+1)$

Comment: That is much more than a hint. Thanks.

Comment: @jay, removed 'HINT', added something else